# How to Disable "Slide" page transition on certain links for certain devices? -defaultPageTransition alone isn't enough

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm working with jQuery Mobile.  For certain links - but not all, I am using the following page-transition code right in my markup:

```
data-transition="slide"
```

This is working well, but I want to disable the slide animation in Android devices, while still allowing the slide animation in iOS etc...

I know I can target Android with code like the following:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {

    if (/Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "none";
    }

});
```

And while that does remove the default transition, my slide transition isn't the default, it's one that I'm specifically specifying in the markup.

Does anyone know how to disable / override a particular slide transition like this in particular devices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perfect solution don't exist because jQM developers didn't implement perfect transition turn off solution.

It can be still done like this:

### Solution 1

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    if (/Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    }
});
```

This will prevent page loading with an ajax thus preventing page transitions. Of course this is a bed solution if you still need pages to be loaded with ajax.

### Solution 2

This solution will be much easier. I am using jQuery Mobile 1.3.1. for this, trust me it is important. Basically you will need to manually change jQuery Mobile js file so use uncompressed one.

Go to line 3788 and there you will see this function:

```
// If transition is defined, check if css 3D transforms are supported, and if not, if a fallback is specified
$.mobile._maybeDegradeTransition = function( transition ) {
    if ( transition && !$.support.cssTransform3d && $.mobile.transitionFallbacks[ transition ] ) {
        transition = $.mobile.transitionFallbacks[ transition ];
    }
    return transition;
};
```

Change it so it will look like this:

```
// If transition is defined, check if css 3D transforms are supported, and if not, if a fallback is specified
$.mobile._maybeDegradeTransition = function( transition ) {
    if (/Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || (!/Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent) &&  transition && !$.support.cssTransform3d && $.mobile.transitionFallbacks[ transition ] )) {
        transition = 'none';
    }
    return transition;
};
```

You can test it here: http://www.fajrunt.org/transition-test/

If you are using an older jQM version tell me which one and I will modify it for you. You can also download modified jQM js file from my example. Don't forget to compress it again.

Comment: It looks like there are a multitude of different ways to "minify" or "compress" javascript - can you recommend a good way for jQuery Mobile?

Comment: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS From what I know jQuery team is using this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the same can be achived like this in 1.3.0 either, like:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {

    if (/Android 2.2/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        console.log("Android 2.2 detected - changing default transition fallback behaviour to 'none'");
        //$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "none";
        $.mobile.transitionFallbacks.slidefade="none";        
        $.mobile.transitionFallbacks.flip = "none";
        $.mobile.transitionFallbacks.flow = "none";
        $.mobile.transitionFallbacks.pop = "none";
        $.mobile.transitionFallbacks.slide = "none";
        $.mobile.transitionFallbacks.slidedown = "none";
        $.mobile.transitionFallbacks.slidefade = "none";
        $.mobile.transitionFallbacks.slideup = "none";
        $.mobile.transitionFallbacks.turn = "none";
    }

});
```